Outlook 365 not sending out attachments which are messages (correspondence)
My company's IT team has been unable to identify the cause or solution to this issue, which is why I'm reaching out for assistance.
The problem seems to be isolated to one user (possibly more, though they may be unaware), where any email with an attached Outlook correspondence is sent successfully, but the recipient does not receive the attachment. To summarize, the email is sent, but the attachment is missing. If there are two attachments—for instance, a PDF document and an Outlook correspondence—the recipient only receives the PDF.
So far, I've tried adjusting various settings within the Outlook application without success, but the issue might be on the server side.
Does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing this? I'd love to assist the IT team, as I’m unfortunately the affected user.
